# Last column in pandas table is reading as Nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have a space separated txt file of 30 columns and labelled rows however pandas is reading it with an extra column and filling that column with NaN, I am not sure why and have no idea how to fix it, please help.

Using

```
data = pd.read_table(filename, header=None)
```

the data is:

```
1  0.5 0.5 0.5.....0.5 0.5 0.5
2  0.5 0.6 0.7.....0.7 0.6 0.5
```

which is then read as

```
    0   1   2  ..... 27  28  29  30
1  0.5 0.5 0.5 .....0.5 0.5 0.5 NaN
2  0.5 0.6 0.7 .....0.7 0.6 0.5 NaN
```

here is a snip of the original data file

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: just tried the index_col = None however  that still produces NaN's

Comment: *A sample without the dots. They obscure the issue.

Comment: Nan = Not a number. You have 29 columns on your data or 30?  maybe you ar reading a empty column for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.read_table(filename, delim_whitespace=True, skipinitialspace=True)
```

Comment: @No problem! Please click the up arrow and the checkmark so others know it's the correct answer.